# The automorphism group of the infinite dihedral group

Tags: group-theory

I showed using a somewhat lengthy but elementary computation that the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(D_{\infty})$ of the infinite dihedral group $D_{\infty} = \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2$ splits as a semidirect product as follows:
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(D_{\infty}) \cong \operatorname{Inn}(D_{\infty}) \rtimes \mathbb Z_2
$$
Here $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ denotes the group of inner automorphisms of a group $G$. The $\mathbb Z_2$ factor in the above decomposition comes from the group homomorphism that interchanges the factors of $\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2$. Since $D_{\infty}$ has trivial center, it follows that $\operatorname{Inn}(D_{\infty}) \cong D_{\infty}$. In particular we see that the group of outer automorphisms is given by $\operatorname{Out}(D_{\infty}) \cong \mathbb Z_2$.

What would be an approach to derive these results using some more theory (which might also be applicable to compute automorphism groups of more difficult groups)?

Comment: The proof given in section $1.4$ [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sthomas/book.ps) is perhaps more interesting for you, and enables to compute the whole automorphism tower for $D_{\infty}$.

Comment: There is a paper by M. Pettet, called [The automorphism group of a graph product of groups](http://math.utoledo.edu/%7Empettet/graph_products.pdf), and a similar paper by Gilbert, Howie, Metaftsis and Raptis, [Tree actions of automorphism groups](http://www.ma.hw.ac.uk/~jim/preprint10.pdf), which you might find interesting. The group $D_{\infty}$ acts on a tree (the $\mathbb{Z}$-tree), and these papers look at groups whose automorphism groups induce an action on the tree. Unfortunately, these methods do not work here - swapping the generators messes up the tree. But the ideas are interesting!

Comment: (Hmm...actually, I think the ideas do apply, because $C_2$ is finite so actually swapping the two copies of $C_2$ doesn't mess the tree up. (In Pettet's paper he talks about Property FA being sufficient for this to work, and finite $\Rightarrow$ Property FA...but I have a niggling feeling that I miss-read this passage in Pettet before and that there is *something more going on*. I need to think about it. But provisionally, Pettet's paper is applicable. Also: look at the diagram in Gilbert, Howie, Metaftsis and Raptis' paper. It is pretty, and explains it nicer-ly than Pettet.))